# Circular dependency: CustomerGroupPlugin depends on Model\Authorization\CustomerSessionUserContext

Tags: magento2, extensions, b2b, magento-2-commerce, magento2-b2b

Circular dependency: Magento\SharedCatalog\Plugin\Source\CustomerGroupPlugin depends on Magento\Customer\Model\Authorization\CustomerSessionUserContext and vice versa. {"report_id":"eae0559822ca428b0a16dd3994d1d4290adc372c6b21381970c5fb48ed31cecf","exception":"[object] (LogicException(code: 0): Circular dependency: Magento\SharedCatalog\Plugin\Source\CustomerGroupPlugin depends on Magento\Customer\Model\Authorization\CustomerSessionUserContext and vice versa.

I am getting the above error after installing b2b extension for the magento2 commerce edition while hitting any of the URL in the front store

Comment: I have the same error. It started to happen so randomly, without reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution for this.
Just clear the cache the problem will be solved.